# C# MouseHover with form control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mousehover

Using C# in VS 2010 Pro.

I have an MDI parent form that implements a MouseHover event on a label.  On MouseHover a form is displayed.  I am not happy with the random positioning of that form.  Is it possible to control where that form is displayed?  I would like it to show where the mouse cursor is.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I have not tried this but maybe something like this would work.  In the MouseHover event get the location of the mouse with this... `this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)`.  Then set the new forms top and left location to this.  If `PointToClient` does not work then possibly `PointToScreen`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on what I meant.  I said " I would like it to show where the mouse cursor is",  I should have said where the label is.  I think you are on to something there though.

Comment: Yeah...PointToClient or PointToScreen should still work, just use label position as parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Location` property on the form to your desired location.

Comment: I think that will work, just not exactly sure how to execute the procedure.  I found a similar issue elsewhere and am reusing that code.

Comment: PrntFrmLctn = GetFormLocation(MDIParentForm);

However MDIParentForm is the name of the form and a reserved class name, how do I get around that?  Sorry if I am missing something obvious...

Comment: @Xantom, I'm not clear on what you're asking. Are you trying to get the parent Form on the child form? Or the child form on the parent form? In either case, that's really a different question entirely.

Comment: Sorry Jon B, I will try to explain.  I have a method GetFormLocation, that will return a Point, the upper left location of the Form passed.  What do I pass as the variable for the form name?  MDIParentForm is reserved, but it's also the form name.  Sorry if I am not explaining this well.

Comment: @Xantom - that sounds like a totally different question. You'll need to post some code to explain it further. I suggest asking that question separately.